# Profile image filling a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i want to make all profile pics of users to fill a div. I managed to fill on 4:3 pics and 16:9 pics but i dont manage to fill portrait ones. My script cuts from both parts bottom and top. What i want is to cut only from bottom of the pic and let the picture start from top. On width pics it cuts from sides and get's the center of the image. On portrait pics i want to cut only from bottom and fill the div. I want my script to work like facebook profile pic. Here is my script:

```
<?
// Input parametres check
$w = intval($_GET['width']);
$h = intval($_GET['height']);
$mode = $_GET['mode']=='fit'?'fit':'fill';
if ($w <= 1 || $w >= 1000) $w = 535;
if ($h <= 1 || $h >= 1000) $h = 452;

// Source image
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('123.jpg');

// Destination image with white background
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagefill($dst, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($dst, 255, 255, 255));

// All Magic is here
scale_image($src, $dst, $mode);

// Output to the browser
Header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst);


function scale_image($src_image, $dst_image, $op = 'fill') {
    $src_width = imagesx($src_image);
    $src_height = imagesy($src_image);

    $dst_width = imagesx($dst_image);
    $dst_height = imagesy($dst_image);

    // Try to match destination image by width
    $new_width = $dst_width;
    $new_height = round($new_width*($src_height/$src_width));
    $new_x = 0;
    $new_y = round(($dst_height-$new_height)/2);

    // FILL and FIT mode are mutually exclusive
    if ($op =='fill')
        $next = $new_height < $dst_height;
     else
        $next = $new_height > $dst_height;

    // If match by width failed and destination image does not fit, try by height 
    if ($next) {
        $new_height = $dst_height;
        $new_width = round($new_height*($src_width/$src_height));
        $new_x = round(($dst_width - $new_width)/2);
        $new_y = 0;
    }

    // Copy image on right place
    imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image , $new_x, $new_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $src_width, $src_height);
}
```

Comment: Just an idea - you don't necessarily need to cut, you can position the visible area and adjust the size via css.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius True, but perhaps it's better to cut off what's not visible anyway from the image, thus reducing the size of the file resulting in faster loading time.